# TYPO3 10.4 How to connect an API to typo3

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

I have a postman collection with an API get request which contain some data.
On my TYPO3 extension, I need to get the data from this API on my Service, but I did not find in the doc, how to connect an API with a TYPO3 project.

I would like a basic example of how to plug an API into a TYPO3 or a guide if possible

thanks you

Comment: I have created a lot of extensions requesting foreign APIs. Here an example extension: https://github.com/jweiland-net/avalex/tree/master/Classes/Client

Comment: How did you search for it? I found a bunch of results on Google. Maybe you need a more specific task?

Comment: @Froemken, thanks I will check it
ThomasLöffler, yes I checked but I didn't found something for my usecase, I found some results about how to create, but not for requesting already made APIs

Comment: @yonea My experiences said that you should not search in TYPO3 context mainly but also for composer packages. There you'll find many direct API connectors which you only need to integrate to TYPO3.

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment but maybe this will help (example talentstorm API json request):

https://github.com/Hauer-Heinrich/hh_talentstorm_job_posts/blob/main/Classes/Http/TalentstormRequest.php

```
$talentstormRequest->setApiUrl("https://myApi.tld/v2/getData");
$talentstormRequest->setApiKey("myApiKey");
$data = $talentstorm->request();
```

For example like here:
https://github.com/Hauer-Heinrich/hh_talentstorm_job_posts/blob/main/Classes/EventListener/TalentstormJobpostsListener.php